# MBProgress view and pushing a view controller doesn't display

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mbprogresshud

MPProgressView won't display when I try to push a viewcontroller until seconds before the pushed VC is displayed. Should the viewController be placed in the same function as the MBProgressView is displayed? I've made sure that my MBProgressView is on the main thread, I've tried many solutions on SO and can't see anyone with the same issue. I am simply trying to display the MBProgressHUD while the viewController is loading and being pushed. Thanks!

I am using MBProgressView as follows:

```
- (IBAction)pushButton:(id)sender
{

    self.HUD =[MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:self.HUD];
    self.HUD.labelText = @"Doing stuff...";
    self.HUD.detailsLabelText = @"Just relax";
    self.HUD.delegate=self;

      [self.view addSubview:self.HUD];
   [self.HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(loadCreate) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];



}


- (void)loadCreate {

  [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(dataLoadMethodMail) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
}


-(void)dataLoadMethodMail
{NSLog(@"data load method is displaying");


   SelectViewController *mvc = [[SelectViewController alloc] init];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:mvc animated:YES];


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to add self.HUD to self.view, showHUDAddedTo: does it for you.

```
[self.HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(loadCreate) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];
```

Shows the hud until `loadCreate` returns.

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(dataLoadMethodMail) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

dispatches something on main thread and returns right after (before the actual end of dataLoadMethodMail). The HUD is shown but disappears right away.

To solve the issue try hiding manually the HUD when `dataLoadMethodMail` finishes it's work.

Just replace

```
 [self.HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(loadCreate) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];
```

with

```
[self loadCreate];
```

and add

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.HUD hide:YES];
});
```

at the end of `dataLoadMethodMail`

PS : Loading data should not be done on main thread.

Comment: Thanks Marcio, that was it! However, when the viewcontroller is pushed, it sort-of "jumps" on the animation. Is that because I'm processing too much on the main thread?

Comment: If you push the view controller after processing your data it should not interfere with UI anymore. Have you tried analysing with Instruments ?

Comment: OK.  Got it.  Everything works perfectly.  I did run Instruments to find leaks, etc awhile back. Is there anything in particular I should be analyzing?